# How to hash key in hash table

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to implement hash table and stuck with the following.
Consider that for key *x* and hash function *h* we have `h(x) = 32`. When size of buckets array is `10`, the index of *x* is `2 (32 % 10)`. When array grows up to `40`, the index of *x* is `32 (32 % 40)`.
How to resolve this?

Comment: If you are going to (frequently) *change length* of the bucket array (but don't want to frequently recompute hashes), you can implement *consistent hashing*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you resize the hash buckets store, you'll need to iterate the old store and reassign them to the new buckets/slots based upon the new modulo of their hash to the number of buckets/slots.

Comment: I wrote it, but it is veeery long to wait until it inserts all 10000 values i gave it. Is there any faster methods?

Comment: It’s going to be essential to reallocate the old items to their proper new slots (the whole point of expanding the number of slots).  If 10,000 items is taking a very long time, you need to pin down where the time is going (profile it).  One possible optimization is to cache each items hash (without module) when you store it.  Then you won’t have to ask each item to recalculate it’s hash.  Hash calculation can be expensive (they generally, should not be for just this reason, so that’s another potential area to tune performance)